# How to install texlive-fonts-recommended (from Debian/Ubuntu) into texlive2012 (CTAN)?

Tags: fonts, packages, installing, texlive, linux

while compiling my tex file, I am getting lots of this error --

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode ljfour --bdpi 600 --mag 0+540/600 --dpi 540 zplmr7v
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for zplmr7v.
dvips: Font zplmr7v not found,  using cmr10 instead.
</usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr10.pk>
dvips: Checksum mismatch in font zplmr7v
```

so far I understood (after googling), I need to install a package called 'texlive-fonts-recommended' which is currently maintained as in the texlive version for Debian/Ubuntu. But I am using the main texlive2012 distribution from the CTAN (http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). How do I do that? I am running a *nix system which is not a Debian derivative.

Comment: Did you actually install the TL12 from TUG? Because it does not place its files in the location you indicate. It seems that you have two LaTeX installations, and your document is not using the correct one.

Comment: Assuming your netinstall was succesfull, try issuing `tlmgr info collection-fontsrecommended`. If it says the collection is not installed, use `tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended`. Depending on your installation directory, you may need root privileges to install new stuff. You  may also need to do the same for `collection-fontsextra`. tlmgr also has a gui (if you like GUIs) that you may call with `tlmgr --gui` (it needs Perl/Tk installed)

Comment: @daleif, yes there were some vestiges from the default texlive installations came with the OS (through Yast), I cleaned them up. But still getting the same error.

Comment: as a general rule, you should not mix CTAN packages with packages provided by your distro, you will break something eventually. Also, CTAN packages are usually more uptodate, so if you already have a working TeXLive from CTAN just stick with it.

Comment: @ramgorur: There is a quite recent version of TL2012 for OpenSUSE in the repos...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

from dcmst's answer --

```
user@host:~$ tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended
```

Some systems might require to run `tlmgr` as root, so add `sudo`:

```
user@host:~$ sudo tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended
```

Answer (score 5):

> sudo apt-get install texlive-full

This solves all the problems but it takes a long time to install :)

Good luck

Comment: Bit of a 'swatting a fly with a hammer'-solution. I much prefer the solution offered by dcmst in the comments, above. Run `tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended`

Comment: I generally try to avoid `texlive-full', my connection is not that fast.

Comment: the other comments are true in principle, but this is the only solution that works for me because neither `tlmgr` nor `sudo tlmgr` was able to work on my system.

Answer (score 1):

`user@host:~$ sudo tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended`   worked for me.

(where `user@host:~$` is the root directory that you can go to by typing "cd /" in the terminal. In iMac that I am using, you can get the terminal screen in the utilities folder that itself is inside the application folder.)

I was stuck for the whole morning.

Thanks very much for saving me days! I would not have solved this problem by myself without the help of this post. Thanks again.